# Audio crashes and loud tone from speakers

Tags: sound, chromebook

Trying to revive an old Chromebook and have been having an issue with Ubuntu distros, including Lubuntu 22.04 and Linux Lite 6.0 (Not a regular distro, but partially based on Ubuntu). If I play a video in any web browser, the audio will eventually stop and the speakers produce a loud, constant tone until I reload or close the page.

Haven't been able to find any information about this. It's not static, popping, etc. Audio sounds fine until it doesn't.

Fedora 36 LXQT didn't have this issue. Tried switching to Pipewire and the issue persisted.

Chromebook is an Acer CB3-111. I realize Chromebooks aren't going to be as compatible, but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be specific with details; *Ubuntu distros* means what exactly?   As Fedora is a GNU/linux just like Ubuntu is, it would be expected to have the same results unless there are differences in the *stack*, but you gave no specific details.  What release/flavor of Ubuntu & release of Fedora?  What kernel choice(s) were made for each?

Comment: Linux Lite isn't a Ubuntu system so is off-topic here (*so is Fedora but that is useful for solutions given it works there*) but you didn't provide release details of Fedora; only the desktop you selected. What version of Fedora did you try (*not the desktop; LXQt is the same desktop as Lubuntu uses; so no difference there except for versions but we weren't given that for Fedora  it's other parts of the stack (closer to kernel) that are where it matters*))

Comment: @guiverc Updated... No kernel choices were made. Ubuntu distros are using 5.15 and Fedora used 5.18 I believe. Also tried using 5.19 with no luck.

Comment: Immediate request for more details then radio silence... figures. Ended up switching to Fedora Cinnamon which works perfectly.

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1451125/124466

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the long tone on audio hardware crash on my Acer CB3-131

sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, at bottom add:

```
# Enables sof debug mode, resolves cb3 hardware audio long tone

options snd_sof sof_debug=1
```

Save changes. Restart laptop.